# Load Whatsapp Stickers from Firebase | Firebase implementation in Whatsapp Stickers App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, whatsapp-stickers

I am confused about loading stickers from firebase. I have the source code of the official app of WhatsApp stickers that I get from GitHub from this link :
https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/tree/main/Android

But I cannot customize this code for getting stickers from firebase storage instead of keeping files in the `assets` folder to reduce the size of my app due to the complexity of the code. If you want source code, you can check the above link. My objective of this question is how we can customize code (link of code is given above) to have firebase functionality.
Kindly help me with this issue of how to customize its code to fetch stickers from firebase
Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Comment: Add some screenshot or code that you tried or error you got.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You'll need to download the files into a folder like internal/external cache, build relevant sticker model & use the `ContentProvider` to send the sticker pack to WhatsApp.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information the Community bot asked for, and please also respond using @.